# Remove the Google Chrome pinned icon on the taskbar

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, taskbar

I want to remove the Google Chrome pinned icon on the taskbar. The uninstall does NOT remove the icon. I modified code to remove just the Google Chrome.lnk. What I want to do (knowing about VBS) is to loop through all the user folders not just the current user which is I believe defined as `strCurrentUserAppData`. The other desire I would like to do with this code is to use it with SCCM to do a clean install of Chrome. I installed the x64 version and need to replace it with the x86 version. When I do the uninstall using the enterprise MSI it leaves the pinned icon. If I use a bat to remove the icon from the directory, the lnk is deleted but there is left a white paper icon on the task bar. So far this is the only code that works on removing the pinned icon.

```
Option Explicit

Const CSIDL_APPDATA = &H1A

Dim objShell
Dim objFolder
Dim objFolderItem
Dim objVerb
Dim objCurrentUserAppData
Dim strCurrentUserAppData
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objCurrentUserAppData = objShell.NameSpace(CSIDL_APPDATA)
strCurrentUserAppData = objCurrentUserAppData.Self.Path



'===================''==================='
' - Remove All Pinned Items -
'===================''==================='


Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strCurrentUserAppData & "\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar")


For Each objFolderItem in objFolder.Items
    'WScript.Echo objFolderItem
    If objFolderItem = "Google Chrome" then
        For Each objVerb in objFolderItem.Verbs
            If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
        Next
    End if
Next
```

The BATCH Code I have run still will not remove the icon even after rebooting.

```
taskkill /im chrome.exe /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleUpdate.exe /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleCrashHandler.exe /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleCrashHandler64.exe /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleUpdateBroker.exe /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleUpdateHelper.msi /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleUpdateOnDemand.exe /f /t
taskkill /im GoogleUpdateSetup.exe /f /t
taskkill /im chrmstp.exe /f /t

MsiExec.exe /X{3EDA268B-C905-37D1-89DF-7049B39FB069} /q/n

MsiExec.exe /X{6A21C1E8-DAC1-3C18-BCDC-2DBB4B352AD8} /q/n

rem app files
rd "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google" /s/q
rd "C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Google" /s/q
rd "\Google" /s/q
rd "%PROGRAMFILES%\Google" /s/q
rd "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Google" /s/q

rem desktop shorcuts
del "%PUBLIC%\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk" /q
del "%userprofile%\Desktop\Google Chrome.lnk" /q

rem start menu folders
rd "%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome" /s/q
rd "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome" /s/q

rem pinned items
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\Google Chrome*.lnk" /q
del "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\Google Chrome*.lnk" /q

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
```

Comment: Not sure whether this will help, but try `for %%I in (%appdata%\microsoft\windows\recent\customdestinations\*) do (find /i "chrome.exe" "%~I" >NUL && move "%~I" "%temp%")` (or whatever backup destination you choose).  If calamity befalls as a result, just move back.  On the other hand, if it solves all your problems, you can replace `move` with `del`.

Comment: The contents of the folder you refer to is a list of flies named like the following `1b4dd67f29cb1962.customDestinations-ms` so the find "chrome.exe" will not be listed will it?

Comment: `find` will scan the contents of each file for the string "chrome.exe".  If found, `&& move` will fire.

Comment: To reiterate, the vbs code I wrote works. How do I loop through the user directories and do it for all users on the system?

Comment: So I should expect to see a file named something like `28c8b86deab549a1.customDestinations-ms` in my temp folder? `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp`. There is nothing there. What about the AutomaticDestinations?

Comment: `for /r "c:\users" /d %I in (*customdestinations) do for %x in (%I\*) do (find /i "chrome.exe" "%~fx" >NUL && move "%~fx" "%temp%")`.  Dunno whether Chrome stuff will appear in AutomaticDestinations.

Comment: Your last code moved a file into the temp dir however the icon is still pinned.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/UZEN0xX.png) Screen Shot

Comment: I doubt that the "Unpin" verb will work for not logged in users.  Sorry Mr. Smith, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Did you tried the code that i posted ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this hybrid code (Vbscript/PowerShell):

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Ws,ByPassPSFile,AppPath,Example,PSFile,MyCmd,Result,MyArray,MyApp,FolderPath,fso
Title = "UnPin application from Taskbar on Windows 7 by Hackoo"
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /k PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
Example = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe "
AppPath = InputBox("Enter the path of your application in order to unpin it from the taskbar " & vbcr & "Example : " & vbcr & Dblquote(Example) & "",Title,Example)
If AppPath = "" or IsEmpty(AppPath) Then Wscript.Quit()
MyArray = Split(AppPath,"\")
MyApp = MyArray(UBound(MyArray))
FolderPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(AppPath)
MyCmd = "$sa = new-object -c shell.application" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$FolderPath = "& DblQuote(FolderPath) & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$pn = $sa.namespace($FolderPath).parsename('"& MyApp &"')" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$pn.invokeverb('taskbarunpin')"
Call WriteMyPSFile(MyCmd)
Result = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,1,True)
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteMyPSFile(strText)
Dim fs,ts,PSFile
Const ForWriting = 2
    PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

**EDIT : 22/06/2015 : UnPinfromTaskBarHiddenConsole.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Ws,ByPassPSFile,AppPath,Example,PSFile,MyCmd,Result,MyArray,MyApp,FolderPath,fso
Title = "UnPin application from Taskbar on Windows 7 by Hackoo"
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
Set fso = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
ByPassPSFile = "cmd /c PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
Example = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe "
AppPath = InputBox("Enter the path of your application in order to unpin it from the taskbar " & vbcr & "Example : " & vbcr & Dblquote(Example) & "",Title,Example)
If AppPath = "" or IsEmpty(AppPath) Then Wscript.Quit()
MyArray = Split(AppPath,"\")
MyApp = MyArray(UBound(MyArray))
FolderPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(AppPath)
MyCmd = "$sa = new-object -c shell.application" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$FolderPath = "& DblQuote(FolderPath) & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$pn = $sa.namespace($FolderPath).parsename('"& MyApp &"')" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$pn.invokeverb('taskbarunpin')"
Call WriteMyPSFile(MyCmd)
Result = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
MsgBox "The Unpin of " & DblQuote(MyApp) & " from the taskbar is done !",VbInformation,Title
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteMyPSFile(strText)
Dim fs,ts,PSFile
Const ForWriting = 2
    PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: I'll check now... I had to re-image the system due to too many bad uninstallers.

Comment: That actually worked it did leave a command prompt open. I had to change the path to the app to C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application. I guess is come cases chrome could be installed in either directory.

Comment: I want to use this to deploy to remote systems. I tested it by creating a vbs file and running it logged into the system as myself. However for it to "work" it must be run remotely from my system on 1000's of systems. Leaving the CMD window open is not acceptable. I will continue to modify and test.

Comment: My OP states: "The other desire I would like to do with this code is to use it with SCCM to do a clean install of Chrome." so I have not yet tested that.

Comment: I just leave the comand to be sure if there is no error on the powershell, so if you want to hide it i will edit and add the code !

Comment: Check my last edit and try it, and i hope that will work for you as you expected !

Comment: Will do! Thank you very much for working on this! I will keep you posted.

Comment: I ran the following command remotely from my machine and it will not run. powershell just hangs. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "ID-TESTCHROME" -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c "c:\temp\chrome\Bradley\Remove-Pinned-v2.vbs" }`

Comment: I figured out there where prompts and removed them and hard coded the AppPath. The only issue is that the task bar still lists the icon and when I click on the Chrome Icon, it immediately disappears (improvement as before it would just list a white page icon) and the error "Can't open this item, It might have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Do you want to remove this item?" Clicking yes or no doesn't matter because the icon is gone. We need to refresh the taskbar?