# VBScript working in English build but not in French build

Tags: vbscript

I have this following script to add shortcut in taskbar. it works perfectly in English build but fails in French builds of Windows 7.

```
on error resume next

Const CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS = &H17
Const CSIDL_PROGRAMS = &H2
Const CSIDL_STARTMENU = &HB


Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objCurrentUserStartFolder = objShell.NameSpace (CSIDL_STARTMENU)
strCurrentUserStartFolderPath = objCurrentUserStartFolder.Self.Path
Set objAllUsersProgramsFolder = objShell.NameSpace(CSIDL_COMMON_PROGRAMS)
strAllUsersProgramsPath = objAllUsersProgramsFolder.Self.Path

' - Pin to Taskbar -

If objFSO.FileExists(strAllUsersProgramsPath & "\TN3270 Plus\TN3270 Central.lnk") Then             'path of the shortcut in start menu
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strAllUsersProgramsPath &"\TN3270 Plus")                   'name of the folder in which the shortcut is placed in start menu
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("TN3270 Central.lnk")                           'Short cut name
Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
For Each objVerb in colVerbs
If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt

Next
End If
```

Could someone have a look and help me out here.

Comment: Please specify what that *fails* stands to. Some error message if you use `on error GOTO 0`? And try to display all the `objVerb.name` as it could be localised?

Comment: Take a look at this hybrid code (Vbscript/PowerShell) :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30920546/remove-the-google-chrome-pinned-icon-on-the-taskbar?answertab=active#tab-top